# How to set similiar lighting

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, light

I wanted to make this nice scene in Blender
[image]
[image]

And i achieved this
[image]
[image]

Present lighting is HDR, the first one is blured version, second and third are normal pictures[image]
I also have 3 sun lamps, one is shining from windows at the front, second from window above the sink and third from behind, they are a bit yellow.

Postprocessing looks like this
[image]

I am not able to achieve so realistic look, but the biggest difference comes from lighting. How to get closer to it?

Comment: "*I also have 3 sun lamps*" Since our earth only has one sun this will hardly give you realistic results, if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: These pictures are also CGi, but you are right. I wanted to make softer shadows and highlights on the ceiling and didn't know where to place area lamps

Comment: The most glaring issue to begin with is that your exposure is well down. In the case of something illuminated by sky or sun, that means that the illuminating source won’t provide nearly enough indirect illumination. Second, the background outside the windows is pegged at an energy level that is vastly too low and as a result, there’s a cognitive dissonance. Start with a single HDRI and use it to illuminate, then work backwards. Don’t apply curves to HDRs, as you break the energy levels with ghastly results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My advices:

1. Your scene and that scene has different type of hdris.
   Install hdri addon like [gaffer](https://github.com/gregzaal/Gaffer) (it's free) and change/rotate different hdris until you find what looks most similar.
2. If you want the most similar look you wil have to use exact same hdri image, if it's possible but in most cases it isn't possible.
3. That scene has hdri of clear noon sky and you have hdri of evening or something like that.
   So both images represent different time span of the day.
4. You image looks darker so after you change the hdri, you should increase the strength of hdri before tweaking the sun lamp
5. The image you are using is already post processed image

So you will have to concentrate on post processing as well as lighting of your scene

6. Blender has good composition system but i would recommend adobe lightroom for this. I use it's free android app to do the post processing.
7. He has used some soft area lamps

Answer (score 1):

It looks like there are a couple of recessed lights in the ceiling of the original. 
It also looks like there is a light panel just out of the camera view, aimed at the beam. It may be “flagged” off of the stools.

When I look at a scene like this, I can often pick up on the lighting by looking at the highlights in shiny surfaces. Also, check for the shadows. They can give it away too.